# testflight external status active but nothing to test

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, ios8.3

My iOS application in prerelease testing process. Last day I sended my application to itunesconnect and send invites to external test group, everything works fine. Everybody was able to test application. Also I’m doing this process for all my other (10+) applications.

But today, I clicked send invites button but till now no e-mail and no application to test in testflight app. Does anyone know a solution/workaround for this problem? Thank you.

[image]

Another interesting detail is when I click on build number there is "Test Information" and "Testers" tabs. Normally I'm able to see external testers there, but this time it says "Internal and external testers can be added in the app’s Prerelease section."

[image]

Comment: When you open Users and Roles and go to TestFlightBetaTesters Internal/External do you see the users? In case of "internal" are they 'checked'?

Comment: @Vive, yes, they checked there. Like I said, last test (Friday) everything was working.

Comment: I understand, but the question is why it's not working now. Maybe some configuration reset or newbie in company changed something? Can you post more screenshots (not enough data to help, draw black lines on any valueable data like appname, version, users): UsersAndRoles->TestFlightBetaTesters(internal+external), App->Prerelease->Internal Testers and ExternalTesters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours now Apple sended push notification and e-mail for it. Now everybody able to test application. I change nothing in itunesconnect site. Now I'm able to see my external tester under tester tab. (instead of writing "Internal and external testers can be added in the app’s Prerelease section")

If anybody will face with same issue in future, this could be problem at Apple side. Means, be patience and don't worry.

Thank you.